# Insert Data into PHP Database via Android Programing

Tags: java, php, android, send

I want sent 2 text variables to php server and store them in database and this is the code
but I get that toast (error) place in catch
where is the problem ?

Android Side

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","android"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mob","203040"));
        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://apptest.ir/test/recive.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data Send !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

and this is PHP File

```
<?php
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$mob = isset($_POST['mob']) ? $_POST['mob'] : '';
$ins = "INSERT INTO table1 (name,mob) VALUES ('$name','$mob')";
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user1', 'pass1');
if (!$link) {die('Not Conected');}
echo 'Conected';
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {die ('Can\'t use table1 : ' );}
echo 'Database is Selected'.'<br />';
$saved=mysql_query($ins);
if($saved){echo "Data STORED";} 
?>
```

Comment: First, there is no such thing as a php database.  You can have a database with a php webservice in front of it.  Second, please post the stack trace of the exception if you want help.  Although in this case I can tell you what it is-  you can't make an HTTP request on the UI thread, you need to do it in a Thread or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Without stack trace it is very difficult for us to see where is problem. But I guess that the problem is because you are doing "network" stuffs from onCreate. From version 3.0 to newer these network stuffs you should run in Thread or AsyncTask. But you can try to avoid this by putting next lines inside onCreate(...)

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```